# Generating two different outputs for the same XSL file?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

This is my XML file and If i run the XSLt file i'll get the same output in the same order exactly in Eclipse XSL Transformation.
Even if add a new record to my xml file and run the XSL file, the `<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>` will create unique id for the new record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>

<CONTACT>
<Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
<FirstName>Ben</FirstName>
<LastName>Foden</LastName>
<email></email>
<address></address>
<state>AZ</state>
<country>US</country>
</CONTACT>

<CONTACT>
<Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
<FirstName>Nimal</FirstName>
<LastName>Anup</LastName>
<email>nimal.anup@gmail.com</email>
<address></address>
<state>TN</state>
<country>IN</country>
</CONTACT>


<CONTACTS>
```

This is my updated XSLT file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<!--Identity template to copy content forward-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
<xsl:copy>
    <Customer-ID>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="generate-id"/>
    </Customer-ID>

    <FirstName>
    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/> 
    </FirstName>

    <LastName>
    <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/> 
    </LastName>

    <email>
    <xsl:value-of select="email"/> 
    </email>

    <address>
    <xsl:value-of select="address"/> 
    </address>

    <state>
    <xsl:value-of select="state"/> 
    </state>

    <country>
    <xsl:value-of select="country"/> 
    </country>

</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id">
    <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number level="single" count="node()" format="100"/>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I used the same XSLT file for XSLT processor function in XUL, which I'm getting a different type of ID and output. 
It's keep generating a new ID for old record and for new record If i add a new record in XML file.

How do i generate a new id only for the new record? and how can i have the same XML template of my input file to my XML output file.

This is the output i'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>

<CONTACT><Customer-ID>id0x03e4a620</Customer-ID><FirstName>Ben</FirstName><LastName>Foden</LastName><email></email><address></address><state>AZ</state><country>US</country></CONTACT>

<CONTACT><Customer-ID>id0x03e4ad80</Customer-ID><FirstName>Nimal</FirstName><LastName>Anup</LastName><email>nimal.anup@gmail.com</email><address></address><state>TN</state><country>IN</country></CONTACT>

<CONTACTS>
```

This is my Javascript to call the XSLT file: The script call this function after saving the XML file. The new record will update in the same as mentioned in the input xml file.

```
function process()
{

var src = readFile("c:\\idgenerator.xsl");
var parsed = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(src, "text/xml");
var stylesheet = parsed.documentElement;

var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(stylesheet );

objXMLDoc = processor.transformToDocument(objXMLDoc);

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var prettyString = serializer.serializeToString(objXMLDoc);

saveFile(prettyString, "C:\\mercredi.xml");

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what you're asking for. You've shown the actual output (from XSLT processor under XUL); what is your desired output? Is it that you want the XSLT processor under XUL to output the same generated IDs as XSLT did under Eclipse?

Comment: The 1st XML file is the actual output of the XSLT file in Eclipse, this is my desired output. The 2nd XML file is the output of the XSLT processor under XUL. My question is why it's generating two different types of output? from the same XSLT file.

Comment: @LarsH: May be Eclipse is using xsl.jaxp and XUL is using XSLT processor. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what XSLT processor Eclipse uses. At least with some extensions, you can configure the processor, e.g. to Xalan or Saxon.
Mozilla/XUL uses Transformiix, at least by default. I read somewhere that it could be made to use Saxon.
There are certainly differences between different XSLT processors.

The specification for [generate-id()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) does not say what the generated ids should look like; only that they "must consist of ASCII alphanumeric characters and must start with an alphabetic character".

If you want XSLT-under-XUL to produce the same kinds of IDs as under Eclipse, you have a couple of options.

1) You could try and get XUL to use the XSLT processor that Eclipse uses. I don't know if this is possible.

2) Implement your own custom template for generating IDs.

With the latter, it would not be hard to imitate the style of the IDs you get in Eclipse, and to make them stable across multiple runs and different XSLT processors, if you have some stable data to base them on.

For example, if the order of your records is always stable (old records will never be deleted, or swapped, or replaced), then you could use a template like this to generate IDs:

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id">
    <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number level="any" count="node()" format="00001"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

If the order is not stable, but the first name + last name is both stable and unique, you could use

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(FirstName, LastName)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: is it correct? <Customer-ID>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="generate-id"/>
</Customer-ID>
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id">
<xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
<xsl:number level="any" count="node()" format="00001"/>        
</xsl:template>

Comment: Yes, that's right, although you will need to make sure you don't have spaces between the tags of `<Customer-ID>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="generate-id"/>` and `</Customer-ID>`. Otherwise those spaces will become part of the ID.

Comment: I followed exactly the way you mentioned but it's not working.

Comment: @karthik, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/auto-smell-the-phrase-it-doesnt-work-and-ask-user-if-enough-info-given ("it's not working" is not enough information to fix a problem.)

Comment: I'm sorry. Generally what happens here, if use the above the template the XST file transformation is not working. I checked with alert message for exmaple: function process()
{alert('1); //Script// alert('2');} alert1 works and alert2 is not working. The XSLT file is loading but the transformation is not happening.

Comment: I don't know, it's possible that there is a syntax error in the XSLT. If there were a syntax error, would you see different behavior (e.g. an error message)? Have you tried the same (updated) XSLT in Eclipse, and did it work there? It maybe be helpful to post your exact, updated XSLT in your question. It's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I tried in Eclipse, it says it couldn't find the output file. I just updated my XSLT file in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @karthik: sorry, I missed the fact that your `<xsl:apply-templates>` had `select="node()"` instead of `select="."`. However that should not affect whether the stylesheet runs or not. It would just give slightly different ID numbers.

Comment: What *would* cause your XSLT not to run is that you don't have the generate-id template in it. See `<xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id">...</xsl:template>` above.

Comment: if I remove this <Customer-ID> <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="generate-id"/> </Customer-ID> <xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id"> <xsl:text>N</xsl:text> <xsl:number level="any" count="node()" format="00001"/> </xsl:template> and try with this way, it works fine<Customer-ID><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/></Customer-ID>. Once again i tried with select="node()" in apply templates the file is not transforming.

Comment: Please check my updated XSLt file. This way it works fine, it generating a big number of id's. "N1N2N3N4N5N6N7N8N9N10N11N12N13N14N15N16N17". Thanks for your support

Comment: @karthik, the reason it's generating many IDs is because you have `select="node()"` in `apply-templates mode="generate-id"`. Instead, you need to have `select="."` so that you are running the generate-id template on the current node, not on its children.

Comment: Great! It works fine. I include the below script by "cuq" so that it won't generate  new id for the existing ID's. Thank you very much.

Comment: @karthik: Great. Thanks for the Accept. I didn't realize you had some Customer-IDs already in your input file... glad you got that taken care of.

Comment: your welcome. I thank you very much for all your support and patience with me.

Answer (score 3):

If generate-id() produces repeatable results in different runs, then that's an accident of the design of your XSLT processor, not a behaviour you can rely on.

Answer (score 0):

generate-id() works that way, you could verify if there are a Customer-ID in the Contact before you use the generate-id() I think...

```
<xsl:if test="./Customer-Id=''"> <!-- if the new contact comes with this empty -->
    <Customer-ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/> 
    </Customer-ID>
<xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(./Customer-Id='')"> <!-- if the contact comes with Customer-Id -->
    <Customer-ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="Customer-Id"/> 
    </Customer-ID>
<xsl:if>
```

Comment: Your function removes the <Customer-Id> from the old record and generates id in <Customer-Id> for a new record.

Comment: yes, isnt complete... 'you could then copy the old value if it exists already'... sorry i didnt mean to confuse...

Comment: The above XSLT code works file but you forgot to close the loop. Thanks for your support.