# XSLT Getting two different output for same input XML for same XSL

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have been trying my XSLT code in the online tool [*XSLT 1.0 processor*]:

http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Recently, I had to make use of `xs:dateTime` and hence started using the tool that uses *XSLT 2.0 processor*,
http://xsltransform.net/

Now, when i was trying to solve a problem, i see that i get different output for the same input XML in these two processors. The code posted here is not the real code i am working on; this is to simulate the weird output i faced.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <book> 
        <title></title>
    </book>
    <phone>apple</phone>
</items>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <items><xsl:apply-templates select="items/*" /></items>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore empty elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />


    <xsl:template match="book">
      <newbook><xsl:apply-templates /></newbook>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
      <newtitle><xsl:apply-templates /></newtitle>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="phone">
      <newphone><xsl:apply-templates /></newphone>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output from `http://xsltransform.net/`  :**   [output 1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <newbook> 
        <newtitle/>
    </newbook>
   <newphone>apple</newphone>
</items>
```

**Output from `http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html`  :**  [output 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <newphone>apple</newphone>
</items>
```

**Expected** output XML is  `output 2` .

Any idea why this different output behavior?

*note: I looked at another SO question: [Generating two different outputs for the same XSL file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764123/generating-two-different-outputs-for-the-same-xsl-file), but that is different.*

***Edit***

To add more clarity on which tool produced which output:

`http://xsltransform.net/` produced `output 1`

`http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html` produced `output 2`

**Update[02/10/2014] - regarding solution**

Since the correct answer was first provided by Jim Garrison, that's marked as answer. However, there are other important points as well, as pointed out by others, Hence I am wrapping up all here.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

The above template eliminates the empty nodes in both XSLT1 and XSLT2. Hence **output 2 is correct**

*Reason for getting *output 1* from the tool - http://xsltransform.net/ :*

1. As @michael.hor257k pointed out, there are two templates that matches the `<book>` element.
2. The tool was using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.3, and the *output 1* behavior was probably a bug that was fixed in the latest maintenance release [@Michael Kay explained well in his answer]
3. As @Ian Roberts mentioned in his answer, there is a concept of  default priorities that are assigned to different types of templates.
   Changing the template syntax to:
   `<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" priority="2"/>`
   yields the same output in both the tools regardless of Saxon version, because we are explicitly defining the priority to the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output 2 is correct.  I ran your example in Oxygen/XML, using both XSLT1 and XSLT2 and got the correct results for both.  Your template

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

eliminates the empty nodes in both XSLT1 and XSLT2.

Therefore the only possible conclusion is that the online tool that produced your Output 1 has a bug.

Comment: To confirm, did you meant to say the tool http://xsltransform.net/  has a bug?  Because that is the one that is giving output 1

Comment: That is correct.  As you said in your original post (_"Expected output XML is output 2"_), and as I confirmed in Oxygen/XML, your Output 2 is correct.  It's not clear from your post which tool produced which output, so I'll edit my answer to remove the reference URL.

Comment: Ok fine. Thanks for trying in Oxygen/XML and verifying.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter to be decided by a majority vote among the various processors.

Answer (score 3):

I get the correct result running with Saxon-EE 9.5.1.4; the xsltransform site is running Saxon-HE 9.5.1.3. It's probably a bug that we fixed in the latest maintenance release; I'll do some chasing to see if I can finger it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that an empty `<book>` element matches two of your templates:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
  <newbook><xsl:apply-templates /></newbook>
</xsl:template>
```

The same thing applies to an empty `<title>` element. Such conflicts must be resolved by the XSLT processor, using the priorities specified in the XSLT specification.

The result you report from http://xsltransform.net/ is generated by Saxon 9.5.1 - an XSLT 2.0 engine. You will get a different result (on the same site) if you switch to an XSLT 1.0 engine (Saxon 6.5 or Xalan 2.7.1).

I don't know if the conflict resolution rules have changed in XSLT 2.0 compared to XSLT 1.0; I am getting a different result myself when using Saxon 8.9 - also an XSLT 2.0 processor. Perhaps we will be fortunate enough to hear from Michael Kay regarding this difference (I have added a Saxon tag to your question to get his attention)..

Comment: oh yes!.. now i see there could be a possibility of `output 2` as well!

Comment: @prash You can get "output 2" from Saxon 9.5.1 too, if you change your "ignore empty elements" template to `<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" priority="1"/>`. This shows that the issue here is indeed a nuance in templates conflict resolution, not necessarily a bug.

Comment: I get the same results (Output 2) with Saxon 6.5.5 (XSLT1) and all three versions (HE, PE, EE) of Saxon 9.4.0.6 in both XSLT1 and 2 modes.

Answer (score 1):

Output 2 is definitely the correct one according to both the 1.0 and 2.0 XSLT specs *for the stylesheet you give in the question*. However you say this is simplified when compared to your real stylesheet.

The thing that makes it work is the [default priorities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) that are assigned to different types of templates. These are the same in both XSLT versions, and a match pattern that involves a predicate will overrule one that is just a single element name test.

However a match that involves hierarchy (e.g. `match="items/book"`) or anything more complex than just a single element name will get the same priority as the `*[....]` rule by default - 0.5. If you've got any of these kinds of patterns in your real XSLT then you need to add an explicit priority higher than 0.5 to the "blank-suppressor" template.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" priority="2"/>
```